# Div over another div

Tags: html, css

This is what I would like to have:

[image]

And this is the code I have created:

**HTML**

```
<div class="main_container">
 <div class="team1">team 1</div>
 <div class="vs">VS</div>
 <div class="team2">team 2</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.team1, .team2 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 8px;  
    z-index: 1;
    height: 50px;
   }

   .vs { 
    float: left; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #0099CC;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
   }

   .main_container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
   }
```

The result is this

[image]

([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zu1mmtz/)) Of course it is not what I am looking for. Do you have any idea?

**EDIT**

In order to make it easier, I could think to place a single div and put a cicle over it:

[image]

Could this be a better idea?

Comment: Please find my fully adjustable answer using some advanced css techniques below. Example on codepen. Trying to understand it might take you to a whole new level :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
.vs { 
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top: 20px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Also, make sure you have

```
.main_container {
    margin-top:40px;
}
```

See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zu1mmtz/2/)

Comment: Ok that is great, but the 2 divs are on the top of the circle. They are not on the middle of the circle as shown in the question. How could I do it?

Comment: @AlbertoRossi, I have updated my answer. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @AlbertoRossi Please also check my answer, you might like it even better.

Answer (score 1):

Set both `team*` and `vs` divs as `display: inline-block;` and vertical-align them:

```css
.team1, .team2 {
    position: relative;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
    border-radius: 8px;
    height: 30px;
}
.team1, .team2, .vs {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 -5px;
}
.vs {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #0099CC;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    opacity: 0.999;
    z-index: 1;
}
.main_container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    background: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_container">
    <div class="team1">team 1</div>
    <div class="vs">VS</div>
    <div class="team2">team 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle;`

```css
.team1, 
.team2,  
.vs {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
        width: 40%;
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
    border-radius: 8px;  
    z-index: 1;
    height: 30px;
   }   
.vs {    
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #0099CC;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}   
.main_container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
 <div class="main_container">
      <div class="team1">team 1</div>
      <div class="vs">VS</div>
      <div class="team2">team 2</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This is very good, but I need the blue circle to COVER the right margin of team 1 and the left margin of team 2 as shown in the picture above.

Answer (score 1):

You do not even need an html element for your vs-circle:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbKNPB

```css
.main_container {
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}
.main_container:after {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: #111;
  content: "vs.";
  font-size: 32px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: -20px;
  line-height: 72px;
}
.team1,
.team2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}
.team1 {
  left: 40px;
}
.team2 {
  right: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_container">
  <span class="team1">team 1</span>
  <span class="team2">team 2</span>
</div>
```